# Trying to create a array with the intersection of two arrays but fails at creating array with the proper structure

Tags: java, arrays, intersection

So, I am trying to create 2 randomly generated arrays,(a, and b, each with 10 unique whole numbers from 0 to 20), and then creating 2 arrays with the info of the last two. One containing the numbers that appear in both a and b, and another with the numbers that are unique to a and to b. The arrays must be listed in a "a -> [1, 2, 3,...]" format. At the moment I only know how to generate the 2 arrays, and am currently at the Intersection part. The problem is, that I can create a array with the correct list of numbers, but it will have the same length of the other two, and the spaces where it shouldn't have anything, it will be filled with 0s when its supposed to create a smaller array with only the right numbers.
package tps.tp1.pack2Arrays;

```
public class P02ArraysExtractUniqsAndReps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nbr = 10;
        int min = 0;
        int max = 20;
        generateArray(nbr, min, max);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] generateArray(int nbr, int min, int max) {

        int[] a = new int[nbr];
        int[] b = new int[nbr];
        int[] s = new int[nbr];
        s[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min));
            b[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min));
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                    i--;
                }
                if (b[i] == b[j]) {
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("a - > " + Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println("b - > " + Arrays.toString(b));
        

        for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < b.length; l++) {
                if (a[k] == b[l]) {
                    s[l] = b[l];
                }else {
                    
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("(a ∪ (b/(a ∩ b)) - > " + Arrays.toString(s));
        return null;
    }
    
    public static boolean hasValue(int[] array, int value) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to create the array without the incorrect 0s? (I say incorrect because it is possible to have 0 in both a and b).
Any help/clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- First, allocate an array large enough to hold the intersection.  It needs to be no bigger that the smaller of the source arrays.
- When you add a value to the intersection array, always add it starting at the beginning of the array.  Use a counter to update the next position.  This also allows the value `0` to be a valid value.
- Then when finished.  use `Array.copyOf()` to copy only the first part of the array to itself, thus removing the empty (unfilled `0` value) spaces.  This works as follow assuming `count` is the index you have been using to add to the array:  Assume `count = 3`

```
int[] inter = {1,2,3,0,0,0,0};
inter = Arrays.copyOf(inter, count);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inter);
```

prints

```
[1,2,3]
```

Here is an approach using a `List`

```
int[] b = {4,3,1,2,5,0,2};
int [] a = {3,5,2,3,7,8,2,0,9,10};
```

Add one of the arrays to the list.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i : a) {
    list.add(i);
}
```

Allocate the intersection array with count used as the next location.  It doesn't matter which array's length you use.

```
int count = 0;
int [] intersection = new int[a.length];
```

Now simply iterate thru the other array.

- if the list contains the value, add it to the intersection array.
- then remove it from the list and increment `count`. **NOTE** - The removed value must be converted to an Integer object, otherwise, if a simple `int` value, it would be interpreted as an index and the value at that index would be removed and not the actual value itself (or an `Exception` might be thrown).
- once finished the `intersection` array will have the values and probably unseen zeroes at the end.

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    int val = b[i];
    if (list.contains(val)) {
        intersection[count++] = val;
        list.remove(Integer.valueOf(val));
    }
}
```

To shorten the array, use the copy method mentioned above.

```
intersection = Arrays.copyOf(intersection, count);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intersection));
```

prints

```
[3, 2, 5, 0, 2]
```

Note that it does not matter which array is which.  If you reverse the arrays for `a and b` above, the same intersection will result, albeit in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you are declaring your intersection array at the top of the method.

```
int[] s = new int[nbr];
```

You are declaring the same amount of space for the array regardless of the amount you actually use.

Method Arrays.toString(int []) will print any uninitialized slots in the array as "0"

There are several different approaches you can take here:

1. You can delay initializing the array until you have determined the size of the set you are dealing with.
2. You can transfer your content into another well sized array after figuring out your result set.
3. You could forego using Array.toString, and build the string up yourself.